# Scene2D actor flashing on screen for 1 frame when supposed to be invisible

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am trying to create an actor with Scene2D, that appears on the screen only when a certain event is triggered. To do so, I use the following code:

```
blackRectangle.addAction(Actions.alpha(0));
optionalStage.addActor(blackRectangle);
blackRectangle.addAction(Actions.delay(0.5f,Actions.alpha(0.7f, 0.5f)));
```

The problem I am having is that when the rectangle is added to the optionalStage, the rectangle appears on the screen for 1 frame, disappears, and then proceeds to fade in as supposed to.

I tried playing with

```
actor.setVisible(true/false);
```

but no luck. Is there a way to prevent that "flash" when the actor is added to the stage, even though its alpha is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
blackRectangle.addAction(Actions.alpha(0));
```

to

```
blackRectangle.getColor().a=0;
```

Comment: ...and the reason you need to do this is that Actions always start on the next frame, so there in your original code, there is one frame where the alpha has not been changed to 0 yet.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try doing this and then post here the result. Thank you.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for the answer!